# how to configure flutter dio package

Tags: android, flutter, dio

I want to use [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package for my network request but I am having error with status code 400. My server accepts data in `application/json` format but I don't know why I am getting the error.I have actually tested the endpoint in both postman and swagger and it's working as expected. Here is my configuration. I have checked other suggestions here but couldn't help me to resolve the issue.
Here is the error message from the logcat.

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DioException [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 400.
E/flutter (15679): #0      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:507:7)
```

My code:

```
            class NetworkRequestUtil {
              static NetworkRequestUtil _instance = NetworkRequestUtil._internal();
            
              factory NetworkRequestUtil() {
                return _instance;
              }
            
              late Dio dio;
            
              NetworkRequestUtil._internal() {
                BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
                    baseUrl: AppConstants.APP_BASE_URL,
                    connectTimeout: Duration(seconds: 10),
                    receiveTimeout: Duration(seconds: 5),
                    headers: {},
                    contentType: "application/json: charset=utf-8",
                    responseType: ResponseType.json);
                dio = Dio(options);
              }
            
              Future post(String path,
                  {dynamic data, Map<String, dynamic>? queryParameters}) async {
                var response =
                await dio.post(path, data: data, queryParameters: queryParameters);
                print("My response data is ${response.toString()}");
                print("My status code is ${response.statusCode.toString()}");
                return response.data;
              }
            
            class SignInRepository{
            
              login({SignInModel? signInModel}) async {
                var response = await NetworkRequestUtil()
                    .post(AppConstants.LOGIN_URL,queryParameters:signInModel?.toJson());
                print("The response from the repository is ${response.toString()}");
              }
            }
            
            class SignInModel{
              String? email;
              String? password;
            
              SignInModel({this.email,this.password});
            
              Map<String, dynamic> toJson()=>{
                "email":email,
                "password":password
              };
            }
            
            
            class SignInController{
            
            Future<void> handleSignIn(BuildContext context)async {
            
                final state = context.read<SignInBloc>().state;
                String emailAddress = state.email;
                String password = state.password;
                try{
                  SignInModel signInModel = SignInModel(email: emailAddress,password: password);
                  processLogin(signInModel);
                }catch(e){
                  toastInfo(msg: e.toString());
                }
              }
              Future <void> processLogin(SignInModel signInModel)async {
                EasyLoading.show(
                  indicator: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  maskType: EasyLoadingMaskType.clear,
                  dismissOnTap: true
                );
            
                var result = locator.get<SignInRepository>().login(signInModel:signInModel);
                print("The result is ${result.toString()}");
              }
              }
            
            final locator = GetIt.instance;
            
            void setUpLocator(){
              locator.registerLazySingleton<SignInRepository>(() => SignInRepository());
              locator.registerLazySingleton<SignInController>(() => SignInController());
```